# JavaScript type script Property 0 is missing in type []

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to have an array of an object as follows.

However typescript throws up an error Property 0 is missing in type []

```
let organisations: [{name: string, collapsed: boolean}] = [];
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What you are defining is a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) (an array with a fixed number of elements and heterogeneous types). Since tuples have a fixed number of elements the compiler checks the number of elements on assignment.

To define an array the `[]` must come after the element type

```
let organisations: {name: string, collapsed: boolean}[] = [];
```

Or equivalently we can use `Array<T>`

```
let organisations: Array<{name: string, collapsed: boolean}> = [];
```

Comment: Then I get this warning: `Array type using 'Array<T>' is forbidden for simple types. Use 'T[]' instead. (array-type)tslint(1)
`

Answer (score 1):

You can define tuples types like -

```
type organisationsType = {name: string, collapsed: boolean};
let organisations: organisationsType[];
```

Remember array the `[]` must come after the element type, like `organisationsType` in above example.